# Aws Emr Cluster creation with RunJobFlowResult unable to take specified config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-java-sdk

I am creating an Aws Emr cluster with AWS Java SDK. Below is the code snippet.

```
JobFlowInstancesConfig jobFlowInstanceConfig = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                .withEc2SubnetId(config.getEc2SubnetId())
                .withEc2KeyName(config.getEc2KeyName()) 
                .withInstanceCount(config.getInstanceCount()) 
                .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)    
                .withMasterInstanceType(config.getMasterInstanceType())
                .withSlaveInstanceType(config.getSlaveInstanceType());

RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName(clusterName)
                .withReleaseLabel(config.getReleaseLabel())
                .withApplications(applications)
                .withLogUri(config.getLogUri())
                .withServiceRole(config.getServiceRole())
                .withJobFlowRole(config.getJobFlowRole())
                .withInstances(jobFlowInstanceConfig);
RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = emrClient.runJobFlow(request);
```

As you can see I am setting "JobFlowRole" using **.withJobFlowRole(config.getJobFlowRole())**, but it is taking default values which does not have permission to create cluster.

I am getting following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AmazonElasticMapReduceException: User: arn:aws:sts::6...0:assumed-role/default-role/i-0...4 is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::6...0:role/EMR_DefaultRole (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: a...f)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1356)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1102)
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JobFlowRole` is the role of EMR service and this is not the role for creation EMR. See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-JobFlowRole).

You should have the right permission to create an EMR where you used to get the AWS credentials. The `iam:PassRole` is missing for your credentials.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. Can you tell me how can I provide user here? Default user does not have permission to create cluster. I need to specify user. Sorry I am new to Aws